# How to add optional variables in the ansible command line and check for their existence in the playbook?

Tags: ansible

I would like to run a particular task only if a flag is given in the command line. For example, I would like to run the ansible-playbook command with the following: `--extra-vars "composer-install=true"`. I would somehow need a task that checks if the `composer-install` variable is set, and if set and equal to true, run the given task which runs `composer install`. I'm not quite sure how to do that last part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you get an error is because you're accessing a variable that has never been set. You seem to be using the existance of the extra-var as an indication that you want composer install to run (i.e. you're never passing --extra-vars="composer-install=false"), so you could go with `is defined`:

```
- shell: composer install
  when: composer-install is defined
```

But the variables can be passed through filters, which can be useful for this case, because it still allows you to pass true/false while not defining the variable at all still works:

```
- shell: composer install
  when: composer-install|default(false)
```

Some more on conditionals can be found here: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html

The jinja2 filters are **very** useful for more than one reason, so more on those here: http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#jinja2-filters

And finally the complete list of built-in jinja2 filters here:
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#builtin-filters

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer, even after I selected another solution as the answer!

Comment: Actually, while I'm here, may I ask how to use the jinja2 filters properly to convert from string to integer and do multiplication? For example, I have a template where I want to set a variable to  `ansible_fact * 2`, and the ansible_fact is a string, as well. I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: There's the "int" filter, and that seems to work (had to test it myself): - debug: msg={{ '2'|int * 2 }}

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the [when parameter](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement).

```
- name: optional composer install
  shell: composer install
  when: composer-install
```

Comment: Thanks, this got me in the right direction. Just doing what you did results in an error. The solution was to also add a "vars:" section to the playbook and add the `composer-install` variable, setting it to "false". Apparently command line variables overwrite the variables set in the playbook. Cheers.